# securing a REST end point for 3rd part applications to connect to

Tags: rest, spring-framework

Im generating a REST database service for an android application to connect to, and have little to no security experience. the service currently uses OAuth2 to secure a web front end with a Spring Boot application. I want to expose a REST service for an android application to access the same data.

My question is this, users are authenticated via the android app, but how can I also secure the REST endpoint for that user to access the endpoint in the same session?

Im not looking so much for an implementation as I am a direction/ technologies that are used so I can learn.

Comment: Will each user have their own username & password on your REST database service?

Comment: Not at the moment.  There really isn't a reason for a user to log in to the db service.

Comment: How will you authenticate the user then? Will you generate a login key automatically in the app (which could get wiped), or will the user be logging in with a Google or other account they already have?

Comment: Is it important that each user is identified separately, or do they all just Read-Only access the same data via the REST service through your app?

Comment: at the moment the users are logging in via Google+ and facebook. and they have unique data on the service. so It would be important to separate them.